# nest two queries: sum & Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum

How do I nest the following two queries?

I am trying to sum `Duration` from table scrap_log and filter via `Reason` but I want to use the matching string from table scrap_reasons where it holds the same product `code` integers.

```
SELECT Reason, SUM(Duration) FROM scrap_log GROUP by Reason
```

```
SELECT scrap_reasons.description, scrap_reasons.code
FROM  scrap_reasons
JOIN scrap_log ON scrap_log.Reason=scrap_reasons.code
```

I tried many different ways of doing this.

scrap_log

| Reason | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 |
| 10 | 40 |
| 11 | 40 |
| 13 | 33 |
| 13 | 33 |
| 11 | 2 |

scrap_reasons

| code | description |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Bad Color |
| 11 | Bad Shape |
| 13 | Bad Size |
| 14 | Bad etc.. |

OUTPUT

| Total | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 60 | Bad Color |
| 42 | Bad Shape |
| 66 | Bad Size |

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so we can understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Your sample data columns don't match your query columns... and assuming the final desired output total is number of rows, it doesn't match the sample data either... so we can't exactly assist with why the count might be wrong. If you only have 60 rows, create a DBFiddle you can share with us.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Your description of how you want output to be a function of input is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select   sum(scrap_log.Duration) as total
        ,scrap_reasons.description
from     scrap_log join scrap_reasons on scrap_reasons.code = scrap_log.Reason
group by scrap_reasons.description
```

| total | description |
| --- | --- |
| 60 | Bad Color |
| 42 | Bad Shape |
| 66 | Bad Size |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3dc95cab52a340bf2c5c7ae9a1ab36d6&hide=1)

Comment: Didn't realize there is such a thing as fiddle, I had the exact same code, but it wouldn't work, so I thought bad syntax on my end! 

However I got the below error and solved it by changing the datatype of description column to varchar! 

Changed datatype to description based on following:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ea7052c6-9aa2-44f7-96ca-ee68ef179cfd/the-text-ntext-and-image-data-types-cannot-be-compared-or-sorted-except-when-using-is-null-or?forum=sqlreportingservices

THANK YOU!